# Symfony mongodb DateTime object in twig do not outputs

Tags: mongodb, datetime, object, twig, symfony

I try to output data in twig my object looks like

```
Pages {#774 ▼
  #id: "5793ec3df788fa291b5fa263"
  #title: "A Foo Bar"
  #creation_date: DateTime {#781 ▶}
  #publish_date: null
  #body: null
}
```

my loop

```
{% block content %}
            <ul>
            {% for page in pages %}
                <li>{{ page.id }}</li>
                <li>{{ page.title }}</li>
                <li>{{ page.creation_date }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endblock%}
```

and when I try to access `creation_date` like `{{ page.creation_date }}` I get

```
Method "creation_date" for object "DashboardBundle\Document\Pages" does not exist.
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: do you have a getter method on the class for return the creation_date attribute? Which visibility have the creation_date attribute?

Comment: its creationDate, not creation_date. When using creationDate you will get getter called getCreationDate()

Comment: Can you show your Pages Entity fefe? @Matteo is right, you need to call the getter instead.

Comment: Thanks for all yes I had to use the creationDate